# Como usar google translate api o alguno similar de forma gratuita?

Tags: java, jframe

Estoy intentando hacer un ejercicio para clase. Se trata de un traductor con ventanas JFrame.
El caso es que intento usar la API  de Google Translate y al parecer es de pago. 
El error que me muestra es el siguiente:

> [google-api-translate-java] Error retrieving translation.

Tengo el siguiente código:

```
private void jButtonEspIngActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                              

        try {

        String textoOrig = (String) this.jTextFieldOri.getText();
        String textoTrad;
        textoTrad = Translate.DEFAULT.execute(textoOrig, Language.SPANISH, Language.ENGLISH);
        this.jTextFieldTrad.setText(textoTrad);
    } catch (GoogleAPIException e) {
        System.out.println("Error " + e);

    }
}                                             

/**
 * @param args the command line arguments
 */
public static void main(String args[]) {

    /* Set the Nimbus look and feel */
    //<editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc=" Look and feel setting code (optional) ">
    /* If Nimbus (introduced in Java SE 6) is not available, stay with the default look and feel.
     * For details see http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/plaf.html 
     */
    try {
        for (javax.swing.UIManager.LookAndFeelInfo info : javax.swing.UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels()) {
            if ("Nimbus".equals(info.getName())) {
                javax.swing.UIManager.setLookAndFeel(info.getClassName());
                break;
            }
        }
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(Tra.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (InstantiationException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(Tra.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(Tra.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(Tra.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
    //</editor-fold>

    /* Create and display the form */
    java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            new Tra().setVisible(true);
           GoogleAPI.setHttpReferrer("http://code.google.com/p/google-api-translate-java/");
        GoogleAPI.setKey("AIzaSyAbr8K-aiuxt8h-dK_vYL12QVpePQgQrpk");
        }
    });
}

// Variables declaration - do not modify                     
private javax.swing.JButton jButtonEspIng;
private javax.swing.JButton jButtonIngEsp;
private javax.swing.JTextField jTextFieldOri;
private javax.swing.JTextField jTextFieldTrad;
// End of variables declaration                   
 }
```

Si me pudieran ayudar! 
Gracias.

Comment: Que problema seria utilizar un WebView? es decir, seleccionar texto y una vez seleccionado cargar un WebView de google translate al cual le pasas el query params con el texto a traducir. Asi es como lo hacen algunas app de android, en lugar de mostrar la traducción directa abren un webview con el google translate. algo como esto pero en un WebView de tu applicación.
https://translate.google.com/#en/es/sometext

Comment: La verdad es que estoy bastante perdida! No sabía de la existencia de WebView, buscaré información! Muchas gracias por su respuesta.

Answer (score 1):

Es correcta tu apreciación: el API de Google Translation (parte del Google Cloud Platform) es de paga (a diferencia de otros servicios, como Maps, que mantienen una capa de uso gratuita); [aquí](https://cloud.google.com/translate/pricing) puedes ver la lista de costos del servicio de traducción.

Una alternativa (viable si solamente estás haciendo ejercicios o aprendiendo la tecnología) es crear una cuenta de prueba de 12 meses. Entra [aquí](https://cloud.google.com/translate/) y da clic en el botón "Try It Free", donde podrás dar de alta una cuenta con crédito suficiente para hacer tus ejercicios; el único inconveniente es que tienes que ingresar datos de una tarjeta de crédito.

Lo importante es que la cuenta que des de alta sea usada como credencial de acceso para el código que ejecutarás; en la documentación describe cómo hacer todo eso en [Java](https://cloud.google.com/translate/docs/reference/libraries#client-libraries-install-java) y otros lenguajes.

PD. Como preguntas sobre alternativas, podrías utilizar también el API de traducción de Bing (Microsoft). [Aquí](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/translator/getstarted.aspx) puedes leer sobre dicho servicio: a diferencia de Google, en este caso si hay una capa gratuita (aunque no "te salvas" de generar una cuenta de Azure para utilizar el servicio).

Comment: La opción de los 12 meses de prueba es tentador, pero me asusta que pasados esos 12 meses me cobren directamente.Lo de Microsoft lo estuve trasteando, pero me parece algo complicado.... No se, se me acaban las opciones... solamente lo quiero para crear un proyecto con ventanas para el modulo...